# Continuous bounded variation path that fails to be Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity, bounded-variation, holder-spaces

Let $C^{1\text{-var}}([0,T];\mathbb{R}^d)$ denote the space of continuous bounded variation paths taking values in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Similarly, let $C^{1\text{-Höl}}([0,T];\mathbb{R}^d)$ denote the space of $1$-Hölder continuous paths. Now, to me it's clear that
$$C^{1\text{-Höl}}([0,T];\mathbb{R}^d)\subset C^{1\text{-var}}([0,T];\mathbb{R}^d).$$
I believe the opposite inclusion fails. Do you agree? If so, can you help me arrive at an example? Any insights will be appreciated.

Comment: [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) seems to do the trick.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Indeed, Cantor function is not Lipschitz... I seem to always forget about the pathological examples xD Thanks for the help.